# React Router Paths, SNICallback, POST, GET

Tags: node.js, express, react-router-v4

I have built the following express app to serve multiple sites with HTTPS from a single server:

```
// strict
'use strict';

// vars
const tls = require('tls');
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var express = require('express');
var vhost = require('vhost');
var forceSSL = require('express-force-ssl');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
var server;
var secureServer;

// always force HTTP -> HTTPS redirect
app.use(forceSSL);

// allow cross origin
app.use(cors());

// Express settings (main switch logic - each host, and each static directory)
var siteOne = vhost('siteone.com', express.static('../siteone/dist'));
var wwwSiteOne = vhost('www.siteone.com', express.static('../siteone/dist'));
var siteTwo = vhost('sitetwo.com', express.static('../sitetwo/dist'));
var wwwSiteTwo = vhost('www.sitetwo.com', express.static('../sitetwo/dist'));

app.use(cors()); // allow cross origin
app.use(siteOne); // all hosts defined above
app.use(wwwSiteOne);
app.use(siteTwo);
app.use(wwwSiteTwo);

app.use(function(req, res, next) { // 404 page as last "use" call
  res.status(404).send('404 page :(');
});

// HTTP Server - http.createServer is enough for our HTTP needs
server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(8080);  // router is set to forward port 80 (http requests) to port 8080

// HTTPS Server - use virtual host to redirect with secureserver
var secureContext = {
    'siteone.com': tls.createSecureContext({
        key: fs.readFileSync('../../sslcert/siteone/privkey.pem', 'utf8'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('../../sslcert/siteone/fullchain.pem', 'utf8'),
        ca: fs.readFileSync('../../sslcert/siteone/chain.pem', 'utf8'),
    }),
    'www.siteone.com': tls.createSecureContext({
        key: fs.readFileSync('../../sslcert/siteone/privkey.pem', 'utf8'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('../../sslcert/siteone/fullchain.pem', 'utf8'),
        ca: fs.readFileSync('../../sslcert/siteone/chain.pem', 'utf8'),
    }),
    'sitetwo.com': tls.createSecureContext({
                key: fs.readFileSync('../../sslcert/sitetwo/privkey.pem', 'utf8'),
                cert: fs.readFileSync('../../sslcert/sitetwo/fullchain.pem', 'utf8'),
                ca: fs.readFileSync('../../sslcert/sitetwo/chain.pem', 'utf8'),
    }),
    'www.sitetwo.com': tls.createSecureContext({
                key: fs.readFileSync('../../sslcert/sitetwo/privkey.pem', 'utf8'),
                cert: fs.readFileSync('../../sslcert/sitetwo/fullchain.pem', 'utf8'),
                ca: fs.readFileSync('../../sslcert/sitetwo/chain.pem', 'utf8'),
    }),
}
try {
    var options = {
        SNICallback: function (domain, cb) {
            if (secureContext[domain]) {
                if (cb) {
                    cb(null, secureContext[domain]);
                } else {
                    // compatibility for older versions of node
                    return secureContext[domain];
                }
            } else {
                console.log('Doing nothing. Domain requsted: ' + domain);
            }
        },
       // must list a default key and cert because required by tls.createServer()
        key: fs.readFileSync('../../sslcert/siteone/privkey.pem'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('../../sslcert/siteone/fullchain.pem'),
    }
    secureServer = https.createServer(options, app);
        secureServer.listen(8043);  // router is set to forward port 443 (https requests) to port 8043
} catch (err){
    console.error(err.message);
    console.error(err.stack);
}
```

So far, I have run into issues with POST, GET, and the react router (v4) paths. For example, a single page site with react router works to every link *as long as* the the user starts from the homepage, but if the user provides a link directly in the url bar (ex. siteone.com/somecoolpath) i get the 404 page from the website switch.

Similiarly I have a POST from a site for adding a user's email to a DB that is on url path /add_email... and I always get a 404 when I send the email...

All these paths work on their own apps, but not when I serve through this SNICallback switch.

Things I have tried but didn't work:

wildcards in the vhost:

```
var reactRouterSite = vhost('siteone.com*', express.static('../siteone/dist'));
```

rewriting the domain in the SNI callback:

```
SNICallback: function (domain, cb) {
    if (domain.includes('siteone')) { // any request from siteone
        domain = 'siteone.com'
    }
    ...
```

a final switch() statement in the last app.use() statement:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) { 
    console.log(req);
    switch (req.url) {
      case '/somecoolpath':
        return siteOne;
        break;
      default:
        res.status(404).send('404 page :(');
    }
});
```

I've spent hours searching around for possible solutions, but haven't even found an example of a case with react router with SNICallback... any ideas what I could try? Or is there a much easier solution?

all the sites are hosted in other node instances, express apps on ports 8081, 8082, etc. For all sites the root pages load as expected through this 'switch', it's just those GET/POST urls and the copy/pasting router urls that don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From dzm's response, I ended up indeed taking out the `vhost` middleware, and instead used an `app.get('*' ...)` route, but instead of rendering a template, I found that a proxy would work best for my needs, and used [the http-proxy package](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy). After some tests, the react router paths can be copy/pasted directly in the browser and work as expected, and the GET/POST methods work as well, as long as the `app.get()` and `app.post()` paths exist also in the website switch.

Replacing the `vhosts` / `app.use()` section, while leaving the other parts of the code i.e. the `SNICallback`, and `secureContext` untouched, the solutions looks like this:

```
// set up proxy server
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({}); // leave options empty --> custom logic below in app.get('*' ...)

// GET paths
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  // custom logic to handle and proxy the request
  console.log(req.hostname);
  switch (req.hostname) {
    case 'siteone.com':
      proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://127.0.0.1:8081' }); // different node server running on local port 8081
      break;
    case 'sitetwo.com':
      proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://127.0.0.1:8082' }); // different node server running on local port 8082
      break;
    default:
      res.status(404).send('404 page :(');
      break;
  }
});

// POST paths (for siteone)
app.post('/new_email', function(req, res) {
  proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://127.0.0.1:8081' }); // this post path must also be written on the index.js of siteone.com
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is get rid of the vhosts middleware and just create a `app.get('*')` route and do the logic yourself checking `req.hostname` and instead of using static directories, render a template.  I've done this with multiple domains and multiple react apps.